# Create SQL Table that will import automatic from Excel whenever that Excel is updated

Tags: sql

So I have an excel spreadsheet with Product and Notes. I'd like to import this information into SQL and everytime people enter more products and notes into this excel sheet, it will automatically updated to the new one whenever I run the syntax?

I finished creating Product - Notes, which I imported current data into that table.I was planning to use insert into function, and every day insert the new values in the table. But this seems too manual.
Is there a way i can do this? The excel spreadsheet is updated daily. 
I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is possible.  You could have the excel connect to your database and then write some macros to save the data to the table when there are changes or new rows are written.

It would not be easy.  There is a lot of complicated logic here and excel was not written to be a front end for a database.

I believe the time spent changing your spreadsheet to work this way would be better spent actually writing a client server application to modify the database using a web application or a local application.  Client server front end applications are easy to write these days with lots of examples, tools and templates.  For someone with experience a simple data entry / modification form is just a couple of days work for a robust application.

Changing the excel file would be much harder.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSIS to import the excel data into your database on a scheduled basis.